# How to remove whitespace and grey box outside of HTML body

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, leaflet

I have an app with a Leaflet.js map and a sidebar.  On the desktop, it appears to look fine, but when I run page inspector and select a mobile version, there is whitespace at the bottom of the page(outside of the map/sidebar), along with an odd grey box.

I cannot inspect either the whitespace or the grey box when I mouseover them with the pointer.  I have tried changing the body CSS to no avail (including no bottom margin/padding for the body).

I am a bit mystified here.  Here's the basic HTML structure:

```
<body>
<!-- links to scripts go here --> 
<!-- Content Starts here -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">                           
            <div class="filterContainer">
                <!-- filter map data with radio buttons here -->  
            </div>

            <div class="filterContainer">
                <!-- filter map data with radio buttons here --> 
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- filter map data with calendar --> 
            <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content">   
            <!-- map -->        
            <div id="map" style="min-width: 100vh; min-height: 100vh">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <span>Filter Events</span>
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

</script>
```

And, some of the relevant CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

    .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

    #sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;      
}

.filterContainer ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
margin-top: -12%;
margin-left: -12%;   
}

#content{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#map{
height:100%;
}
```

And, finally, an image of the problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why isn't your HTML filling the whole screen?

Comment: Can you show all the code please?

Comment: I am closing this; thank you for your responses.  Setting the body to position:fixed; in CSS did the trick.  Thank you.